# Accessing silverlight object data from aspx page

Tags: asp.net, silverlight

I am new to silverlight and I am wondering if it is possible to access silverlight object data from the aspx page that host it. Or have silverlight write to a hidden field on the page on client side.

What I am trying to do is to use silverlight to upload file via WCF (client to WCF Service  directly instead of posting data back to the web server then forwarded to WCF service). When uploading a large file, user can still do some data entry etc. And once the upload is done have it write some data return by the WCF service to the aspx's hidden field and postback to the server on submit.

any suggestion would be appreciated 
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silverlight support javascript interop. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645076%28VS.95%29.aspx) for more details.

Comment: just a quick example on how to call host javascript function in SL
HtmlPage.Window.Invoke("CallMe", "data here!!");